# Insert with returning a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to insert a record in an m:n table (User-Group Relation) and return the group when the user successfully joined.

But I can't manage to return the whole group after the insert.

```
with "group" as (
    SELECT * from "group" where code = 'tohubo' LIMIT 1
)
insert into group_users__user_groups ("group_users", "user_groups")
    select id from "group", 1 
returning (SELECT * from "group")
```

With that query I currently get the error message

> subquery must return only one column

I also tried to just return *, but then I only get the content of group_users__user_groups.

I also tried to add an additional Select at the end:

```
with "found_group" as (
    SELECT * from "group" where code = 'tohubo' LIMIT 1
)
insert into group_users__user_groups ("group_users", "user_groups")
    select 1, id from "found_group";
Select * from "found_group";
```

But then the WITH part is not defined in the second query:

> Kernel error: ERROR:  relation "found_group" does not exist

Comment: in Oracle we need to write `Insert` first then `with` and then `select` from table or inline table name. Check once whether you also need to make similar changes.

Comment: `select id from "group", 1 ` this part is not clear - are you trying to join "group" with 1?.. cos if you want to insert two values it should be `select id,1 from "group" `

Comment: btw http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html so was not meant to return those two column on returning *?..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `returning` clause can only return data that was affected by the insert.

And you can only have one "final" statement in a CTE, not an insert **and** a select.

But you can simply move the insert into a second cte, and then have a single SELECT at the end that returns the data that was found

```
with found_group as (
    SELECT * 
    from "group" 
    where code = 'tohubo' 
    LIMIT 1
), inserted as (
   insert into group_users__user_groups (group_users, user_groups)
   select 1, id 
   from found_group
)
Select * 
from found_group;
```

Comment: How can i return inserted `group_users` value (= 1) in final `select * from found_group`?